# Virtual Packages ; offline installation problem

Tags: apt, package-management, python, apt-cache

I have a problem with offline installation of a package. For instance; `python-qt4` module requires `sip-api-8.1` but it is a virtual package, hence there is no .deb file to install. How can I fix this situation? I know that `python-sip` package provides it, but I am looking for a general solution.

```
$ apt-cache show python-qt4
Package: python-qt4
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 12103
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Python Modules Team <python-modules-team@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Version: 4.9.1-2ubuntu1
Replaces: python-qt4-dev (<< 4.4.4-3~)
Provides: python2.7-qt4
Depends: python2.7, python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2), python (<< 2.8), libc6 (>= 2.3), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libpython2.7 (>= 2.7), libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqt4-declarative (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqt4-designer (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqt4-help (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqt4-script (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqt4-scripttools (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqt4-svg (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqt4-test (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqt4-xmlpatterns (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqtassistantclient4 (>= 4.6.3), libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0-1~), libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), sip-api-8.1
Suggests: python-qt4-dbg
```

However:

```
$ apt-cache show sip-api-8.1
N: Can't select versions from package 'sip-api-8.1' as it is purely virtual
```

**EDIT:**
How does this select python-sip instead of the original?

```
$ apt-get install -s sip-api-8.1
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-sip' instead of 'sip-api-8.1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `python-sip` provides `sip-api-8.1`:

```
$ apt-cache show python-sip | grep Provides
Provides: python2.7-sip, sip-api-8.0, sip-api-8.1
```

How can you find that out for yourself?

```
$ aptitude show sip-api-8.1
No current or candidate version found for sip-api-8.1
Package: sip-api-8.1
State: not a real package
Provided by: python-sip
```

or, using grep-dctrl in `dctrl-tools`:

```
$ grep-aptavail -F Provides -s Package,Provides sip-api-8.1
Package: python-sip
Provides: python2.7-sip, sip-api-8.0, sip-api-8.1
```