# install Electum (BTC) on offline live USB

Tags: live-usb, offline, bitcoin

I would like to install the bitcoin client [Electrum](http://electrum.org/) on an offline live USB drive. This would help to create and restore wallets most securely.

The [install instructions](http://electrum.org/download.html) are as follows:

Install python-qt4 and pip:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-pip
```

Install electrum:

```
sudo pip install http://download.electrum.org/Electrum-1.8.1.tar.gz#md5=dc9f4b1cb38bd1d152be83d0a430cf62
```

Run:

```
electrum
```

What would be the way to do this offline?

EDIT:

The packages can obviously be downloaded and copied to the USB drive. However, I can't get python-qt4 to install. There is a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167104/virtual-packages-offline-installation-problem), but I don't understand how to go through this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "I can't get python-qt4 to install"? Did you get an error?